# How to deploy django 1.5 with FastCGI

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

How to deploy django 1.5  with FastCGI

I could not find flup package for python3!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [uwsgi](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/) instead, it's like FastCGI, but way better.

Check it out B)